# Start python script on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, startup

I have got a problem with some python script to run on startup. I have write a script to track temperature on a raspberry pi 3. It works great but it didn´t run on startup.

How my program works: it tracks every 30 sek for 4 weeks the temperature data and write it into a csv file

I write the code in my /etc/rc.local above (i used sleep because i have read that the problem could be that rc.local starts the script to fast after startup)

```
sleep 15 && sudo python3 /home/pi/Schreibtisch/pythoncsv.py &

exit 0
```

The script didn´t start on Startup

Comment: You don't need `sudo` before your commands; `rc.local` is run as root.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working could be many, I would do the following:

1. Set the execution bit? You can check that it is set by using `ls -la /etc` and then you can set it by running the command `sudo chmod +x rc.local`. You can also use the command `sudo sysv-rc-conf` to check if `rc.local` is enabled.
2. Check that `rc.local` is correctly processed by simply creating a debug file, as with `touch /home/pi/executed`.
3. If the `executed` file is created it could be a problem of your Python interpreter that for some reason is not found, try using a full path, i.e. replacing `python` with the output of `which python`.
4. Check the stdout and stderr of your Python script.

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Now it works. Point 3 works for me.